# My function for a hangman game in C is not working

Tags: c

A specific function for my hangman game in C, **int hidden_word** i cant seem to get right. Its purpose is to display the underscores of the missing letters aswell as the correctly guessed letters. Below are two pictures to demonstrate what the result looks like so far. Obviously the underscores arent even in the second picture. Here is a description from the header file -

// hidden_word()

// Creates the word that is displayed to the user, with all the correctly guessed letters shown, and the rest displayed as underscores.
Any non-letters (punctuation, etc) are displayed.

// The function takes two strings as inputs.  word[] is the word that the player is trying to guess,

// and display_word[] is the output string to be displayed to the player.  The guesses array is a binary
// array of size 26 indicating whether each letter (a-z) has been guessed yet or not.
// Returns 0 if successful, -1 otherwise.

[what its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Epjd.png)

[what is actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDXNN.png)

```
int hidden_word ( char display_word[], char word[], unsigned char guesses[26] ){



int result = 0;

  int l = strlen(display_word);
    if (l != strlen(word))
        return -1;

    printf("%d", l);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        char c2 = (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z') ? word[i] + 32 : word[i];

        if (guesses[c2 - 97] == 1)
        {
            display_word[i] = word[i];
        }
        else
        {
            display_word[i] = '_';
            result = -1;
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Is this pset of cs50?

Comment: As far as I can see this function does not actually print anything except for `l`. How are you displaying the text in `display_word`?

Comment: How is `display_word` initialized?

Comment: @Gerhardh this is from a header file from the game
// hidden_word()
// Creates the word that is displayed to the user, with all the correctly guessed letters
// shown, and the rest displayed as underscores.  Any non-letters (punctuation, etc) are displayed.
// The function takes two strings as inputs.  word[] is the word that the player is trying to guess,
// and display_word[] is the output string to be displayed to the player.  The guesses array is a binary
// array of size 26 indicating whether each letter (a-z) has been guessed yet or not.
// Returns 0 if successful, -1 otherwise.

Comment: That does not help. Where do you terminate the string?

Comment: What values do you pass to that function. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gerhardh looking back at the code i havent passed any values to that function

Comment: What is your definition of "successfull"? You return `-1` if a character was not yet guessed. The function still could create the string successfully.

Comment: If you don't pass anything, you cannot call the function at all. That does not make sense.

Comment: I assume successful means a correct guess at a letter of the word.

Comment: oh wait its called in the h. file    char hidden_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH] ; @Gerhardh

Comment: No, that's not calling your function. I mean a function call. You must call your function if you want to execute it. Is that your hangman game or why do you have to assume about "successfull"?

Comment: why use an array <bool> when you could just logical_OR into an integer? I know this is from the header file, but i don't see why you would use an array to hold boolean information.... might aswell create structs of type "letter" ...

Comment: If the calling code is not your code and you don't know what is passed, just print the parameters. I guess your first check fails because `display_word` is not initialized in the way you expect.